# Geometry dash lite to Geometry dash full version

Tags: geometry-dash

I currently have the Geometry Dash lite version and I want to buy the full version. Can I login with my account of Geometry Dash lite and keep everything I already had? It would suck if I had to redo everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your data over from *Geometry Dash Lite* to the full version of *Geometry Dash* by using the accounts feature within the app.

Simply log in with an account and backup your save to cloud. Finally, in the full version, log in again and this time, load your save from the cloud.

As usual, you can return to the Lite version using the save file. However, missing features in the app will not become available to you (i.e. other character icons or tracks).